# Orthogonality relation in $L^2$ implying a polynomial is constant

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, curves

Let $\phi(t):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous $L$-periodic function such that $\int_0^L e^{i \phi(t)}dt= 0$, which is the complex numebr notation for saying that the curve obtained by integrating $(\cos\phi(t),\sin \phi(t))$ over $[0,L]$ is closed and $C^1$.

Let now consider a polynomial $p(t)$ such that
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \;\;\;\; \int_0^L e^{i \phi(t)} (p(t))^n dt= 0,
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \;\;\;\; \int_0^L \cos\phi(t) (p(t))^n dt=\int_0^L \sin\phi(t) (p(t))^n dt= 0.
$$

**Is there an elegant way to tell $p$ must be a constant?**

What I could come up with till now is just a force brute approach, that looks at minima and maxima of $p$ on different domains depending on the behaviour of $\phi$, which also does not seem to work if zeros of $\cos\phi$ or $\sin\phi$ accumulate.

Note that by looking just at even powers we can assume $p$ is everywhere $\geq 0$ on $[0,L]$. Besides, since the constraints remain true if we multiply $p$ by a scalar, we can also assume $p > 1$ on a subset of measure aribitrarily close to $L$ (we cannot guarantee $p>1$ on neighborhoods of roots, which can be made arbitrarily small).

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is a topology problem. Since the $\sum c_n p(t)^n$ are dense in the $f(p(t))$ your constraint is equivalent to : for all $a\in p ([0,1])$ if $\forall b\in p^{-1}(a), p'(b) \ne 0$ then $\sum_{b \in p^{-1}(a)} \frac{e^{i \phi(b)}}{p'(b)}=0$. The problem is to find if gluing those constraints is possible when $\phi$ is real continuous periodic.

Comment: @reuns I completely missed your comment, sorry. That makes a good point. I got the same equivalent constraint by looking at integrals over $p^{-1}([a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon])$ and taking the limit for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, but your method looks much more elegant. Can you explain it a bit more deeply? The passage from having density to the condition on the sum is not completely apparent to me. Thanks.